# Cannot use android.support.constraint.Group in Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to group the widgets on my layout using a Constraint Layout group `android.support.constraint.Group`, but despite adding the gradle dependency (`implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'`
), Android Studio does not seem to recognize this tag in xml. Here's my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.udemy.mehdi.materialanimations.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/start"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/android"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
    <android.support.constraint.Group
        android:id="@+id/group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="image,recyclerView"
        android:visibility="visible"
        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The error I get when I perform build is as follows:

```
Error:error: attribute me.john.myapp:constraint_referenced_ids' not found.
```

I am using the following Gradle configuration:

```
repositories{
google()
center()
}
dependencies{
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

}
```

Comment: try using   `implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta5'`

Comment: Yeah @Raghunandan this solved the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try a higher version of ConstraintLayout

implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta5'